# Regular expression until a particular word

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following data in a very big string `str`:

```
"RewrittenQuery: Word:(\"state\" \"states\" \"state s\") Word:(\"library\" \"libraries\" \"libr\" \"lib\" \"lbry\") adjust:1feature:#:\" _MetaTag_Category 11265\"\r\n"
```

I want everything that starts from RewrittenQuery till just before `adjust`.
I have written the following code:

```
Match extraction = Regex.Match(str, @"RewrittenQuery:[^\n\r]+");
```

The above code is able to extract the starting point from `RewrittenQuery`, but I don't need data from (including) `adjust`
What should I add the above Regex to get the data that I want?

Comment: Please make sure that the input appears here *exactly as you have it*. No extra quotes and no extra escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, please

```
static void TestRegEx()
{
    string input = "sdsafff RewrittenQuery 1sdfs se1adjust  wer aasdfsd";

    Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"RewrittenQuery(?<A1>.*)adjust");
    if (m.Success)
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["A1"]);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Didn't match");
}
```

prints `1sdfs se1`

The regular expression is `RewrittenQuery(?<A1>.*)adjust`. The part `(?<A1>.*)` takes any symbols and place them into group with name `A1`, so if the input string matches, you may find this value in groups collection of the match by name.

Answer (score 0):

If your end anchor is `adjust:` you can use the following code:

```
string pattern = @"(?<Value>RewrittenQuery:[^\n\r]+\s)(?:adjust:)";
RegexOptions regexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline;
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, regexOptions);
string targetString = @"RewrittenQuery: Word:(\""state\"" \""states\"" \""state s\"") Word:(\""library\"" \""libraries\"" \""libr\"" \""lib\"" \""lbry\"") adjust:1feature:#:\"" _MetaTag_Category 11265\""\r\n";

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(targetString))
{
    if (match.Success)
    {
        var value = match.Groups["Value"];
    }
}
```